# Python/Pandas: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a plot from two columns in a .csv file. The column for the x-axis is in the short date format mm/dd/yyyy while the column for the y-axis corresponds to absorption measurement data as regular numerical values. From this, I am also trying to gather a linear regression line from this plot. Here is what I have so far:

```
mydateparser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y')

df = (pd.read_csv('calibrationabs200211.csv', index_col=[], parse_dates=[0],
                  infer_datetime_format=True, date_parser=mydateparser))

if mydateparser == '%m/%d/%y':
    print('Error')
else:
    mydateparser = float(mydateparser)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,7.5))

x = df.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = df.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)
linear_regressor = LinearRegression()
linear_regressor.fit(x, y)
y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(y)

plt.scatter(x, y, color='teal')
plt.plot(x, y_pred, color='teal')

plt.show()
```

However, I am getting an error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-272-d087bdc00150> in <module>
     12     print('Error')
     13 else:
---> 14     mydateparser = float(mydateparser)
     15 
     16 plt.figure(figsize=(15,7.5))

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'
```

Furthermore, if I comment-out the If Statement, I end up getting a plot, [but with a faulty linear regression.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLtLm.png) I am fairly new to python, matplotlib, and pandas so any help or feedback is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your if/else block is useless, try to eliminate it and see if you reach your goal.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The image embedded in the last bit shows what happens when I remove the if/else block. Can I not parse out the datetime from the lambda function? I am trying to turn the date column into a string or integer so that the plot can easily generate an x-axis.

Comment: i suspect you can't make linear regression on dates, unless you totally sure you want it... The code that follows your if/else block just plots the results of your analysis, as you intend it.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in Python can be used as variables, which is what you are doing here.  If you want to use the result of a function for something, you need to call it by adding () after the function name.

mydateparser is a function, mydateparser() is the result of calling that function.

Additionally, I don't think the comparison you're making makes sense.  datetime.strptime  returns a datetime object, which you are later comparing to a string. I'm actually not sure what you're trying to accomplish with that block at all.

Your regression needs the dates to be converted to some sort of numeric value to regress against.  I would suggest using matplotlib's date conversion functions, specifically date2num, to try this.

Should be something along the lines of:

```
from matplotlib import dates
...
x = df[0].apply(dates.date2num)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and do I apologize for the confusion. I was under the impression that the datetime object is a string. The simplest explanation I can give you that I am trying to turn the date column from a .csv file into a possible integer or string so that the plot can easily generate an x-axis.

Comment: Try one of matplotlib's date conversion functions: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/dates_api.html.

Specifically, use date2num to get an numeric value for each of your dates that you can use in a regression.  Should just need: 
from matplotlib import dates
then you can convert the date column to integers with:
df[0] = df[0].apply(date2num)

Comment: Added code to roughly get what you want to my post.  However, you need to figure out what you want to regress against.  Is day level granularity enough or do you need a more finely grained value for your datetimes? Date2num gives number of days since 00:00 UTC, which might be what you want.

Comment: @nano_horizon Yo, check my edit. Might be what you want.  Can't remember if you get notified just by responses.

Comment: Got your reply. Thanks so much, homie. Also, nice incorporation of a palindrome for your username.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the lambda for it to function.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the code, you declared mydateparser as lambda function.
But float() function only accepts strings or numbers.

I assume you are using date column as a feature for linear regression model which doesn't make sense.

Instead, you can derive new features like month,year,date,weekday/weekend to be used for linear regression.

If you are looking to predict the value for next dates, you can look at time series forcasting models.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I will look into your suggestion. The image embedded in the hyperlink at the bottom of my question shows that the x-axis has the dates but the linear regression is erroneous. To solve this, I am trying to turn the date column into strings or integers. I suppose I'll have to go into the .csv file itself and do that manually.